# Selenium WebDriver - Unable to retrieve All the Elements from the List

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

Unable to retrieve All the Elements from the List 
I have tried to use “Select”, It is throwing Error message. Can anyone please advise me, how to retrieve all the element? Current code is only retrieve only 5 elements. Please check the output of my code

**Following is the list of Element from Website**

```
<h3 class="tout__title complex-link__target theme__target">   Almost Naked Animals </h3>
<h3 class="tout__title complex-link__target theme__target">   Amazing Animal Births </h3>
<h3 class="tout__title complex-link__target theme__target">   American Dad! </h3>
<h3 class="tout__title complex-link__target theme__target">   An Audience with... </h3>
<h3 class="tout__title complex-link__target theme__target">   Arsenal Pre-Season Friendlies </h3>
<h3 class="tout__title complex-link__target theme__target">   Atlanta Plastic </h3>
<h3 class="tout__title complex-link__target theme__target">   Audi Cup </h3>
<h3 class="tout__title complex-link__target theme__target">   The Avatars </h3>
```

**My code is :**

```
wait.until(visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("h3[class='tout__title complex-link__target theme__target']")));

List<WebElement> pgm= alp.findElements(By.cssSelector("h3[class='tout__title complex-link__target theme__target']"));

System.out.println(pgm.size());

for(WebElement e: pgm)
{
    System.out.println("List of Shows "+e.getText());
}
```

**Output :**

```
Size of the Element(Total) :8
List of Shows Almost Naked Animals
List of Shows Amazing Animal Births
List of Shows American Dad!
List of Shows An Audience with...
List of Shows Arsenal Pre-Season Friendlies
List of Shows Atlanta Plastic
List of Shows 
List of Shows
```

Comment: It `pgm.size()` == 8 really? If yes, I strongly doubt that html code you posted is correct. Do you have a link to this site?

Comment: HI Ivan -- the site is : https://www.itv.com/hub/shows .  please advise me if you have solution

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that page's content is being `lazy-loaded` as the page is scrolled down. So, your code shows text for first several items that appear on screen.

You need to add page scrolling for other elements to be loaded. E.g. scroll to the bottom of the page:

```
((JavaScriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

After page is scrolled execute all your element text related code and it should produce now desired results